# How to find the last previous-sibling equal to something and first following-sibling equal to something?

Tags: xml, xslt

1/ I have a list of events with a date in a xml.
I'd like to print each event with its date in a CSV form. If the date is 01/01/1900, then search the last previous sibling different of 01/01/1900

For example :

```
<Events>
<Event>
  <Date>17/01/2012</Date>
  <Description>Event 1</Description>
</Event>
<Event>
  <Date>01/01/1900</Date>
  <Description>Event 2</Description>
</Event>
<Event>
  <Date>01/01/1900</Date>
  <Description>Event 3</Description>
</Event>
<Event>
  <Date>20/02/2012</Date>
  <Description>Event 4</Description>
</Event>
<Event>
  <Date>01/01/1900</Date>
  <Description>Event 5</Description>
</Event>
<Event>
  <Date>01/01/1900</Date>
  <Description>Event 6</Description>
</Event>
</Events>
```

results in:

```
17/01/2012;Event 1
17/01/2012;Event 2
17/01/2012;Event 3
20/02/2012;Event 4
20/02/2012;Event 5
20/02/2012;Event 6
```

2/ I have a list of events with a date in a xml.
I'd like to print each event with its date in a CSV form. If the date is 01/01/1900, then search the first next sibling different of 01/01/1900

For example :

```
<Events>
<Event>
  <Date>17/01/2012</Date>
  <Description>Event 1</Description>
</Event>
<Event>
  <Date>01/01/1900</Date>
  <Description>Event 2</Description>
</Event>
<Event>
  <Date>01/01/1900</Date>
  <Description>Event 3</Description>
</Event>
<Event>
  <Date>20/02/2012</Date>
  <Description>Event 4</Description>
</Event>
<Event>
  <Date>01/01/1900</Date>
  <Description>Event 5</Description>
</Event>
<Event>
  <Date>01/01/1900</Date>
  <Description>Event 6</Description>
</Event>
<Event>
  <Date>30/03/2012</Date>
  <Description>Event 7</Description>
</Event>
</Events>
```

results in:

```
17/01/2012;Event 1
20/02/2012;Event 2
20/02/2012;Event 3
20/02/2012;Event 4
30/03/2012;Event 5
30/03/2012;Event 6
30/03/2012;Event 7
```

I don't find the way to do a lookup of next or previous item equal to a value.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, try:

```
<xsl:template match="/Events">
    <xsl:for-each select="Event">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Date='01/01/1900'">
                <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::Event[Date!='01/01/1900'][1]/Date" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="Date" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Description" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that `preceding-sibling` is a [reverse axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates): the closest preceding-sibling is the first one, not the last one.